# How Can I use MongoDb with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I have a controller that I can use the functions in the template. I am using IONIC, but I can't access the mongoDB, How can I do it ? I have no idea how to do this.

```
$scope.InsertUser = function(){
    user = $("#NameId").val();
    db.users.insert(user);
}
```

so the log wrote "db is not defined", I agree that I cant use this on clientSide but Where is the serverSide ?. my project directory tree:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGsGf.png)

I've already saw a lot of videos or tutorials but is the same place I declare the line : db.users.insert(user);

I do not understand Where I need to declare my collections or where I can put my CRUD methods.

Comment: http://mean.io/#!/ is all you need.  Or look for Mean-seed type projects in github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need declare all of this in the server side. I'm not sure which sever side you uses ,but I uses play framework with java as server side. What I do is triggers a GET request from angular with restAngular , to a function in the server side.
example:

client side:

```
return: function(){
    restAngular.all("/get").get().then(function(result){
        $scope.array = result;
    })
}
```

(the GET request will get it response from this function)server side:

```
private final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
private final MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
private final MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection = MongoDatabase.getCollection("posts");
public static Result getResult(){
return usersCollection.find().sort(descending("date"))
                              .limit(limit)
                              .into(new ArrayList<Document>());
}
```

this is just a little example how to do it with angular as client side and java as server side. for more help you can comment her.